# Getting SQL syntax error from browser but not editor

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write a sql syntax, but it keeps giving me an error even when dreamweaver is saying there is no error. Any feedback would be appreciated.

This is what I have:

```
$inner_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = ".$row['id']." ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I have tried putting backslashes in front of the second set of quotes, but to no success.

I have tried this as well

```
('SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = ".$row['id']." ORDER BY name')
```

but still giving me error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY name ASC' at line 1

I have tried this as well

```
('SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = '.$row['id'].' ')
```

but still giving me error. This is what I used on another page and it's working. I copied pasted the exact code and now it's giving me an error.

I have tried this as well

```
('SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = ".$row['id']." ')
```

I have tried this as well

```
("SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = '.$row['id'].' ")
```

I have tried this as well

```
("SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = '.$row["id"].' ")
```

Of course when trying some of the above, dreamweaver is telling me that there are syntax errors.

Here is part of the code:

```
$inner_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = ".$row['id']." ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysql_error());  
if(mysql_num_rows($inner_result) > 0){
    echo '  </div>
        <ul>';
    while($inner_row = mysql_fetch_array($inner_result)) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="row-name"><?= $inner_row['name'] ?></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the “it” that is giving you an error, and what is the error message?

Comment: Sorry! Should have mentioned it. The broweser is giving me the error which is :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY name ASC' at line 1

Comment: For the sake of debugging: could you try and `echo "SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = ".$row['id']." ORDER BY name ASC";` before you pass it to the function and view the output? Maybe the `$row['id']` is empty or contains non-numeric characters.

Comment: It's not empty, I'm using the same code in the CMS portion and it is displaying. Also in my database the columns are populated.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this instead, put a space after `=`

```
"SELECT * FROM product WHERE manID = ".$row['id']." ORDER BY name"
```

Comment: No. Still same error. Would it help if I put the whole code up?

Comment: I put up as much of the code as the editor would allow me to.

Comment: What's the value of `$row['id']`?

Comment: It's the actual id of each product and I've set it to auto increment. It's an INT. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you `echo` the query to see; how it looks when it hits DB?